# How to run different files without manually changing the configuration?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm and I have an issue. I can't just click run and run files on their own, if they are in a project file. I can, but I need to keep changing and deleting the 'configurations' at the top right every time I switch files. It keeps creating new configurations every time I open a new file, which is why I changed the default value of 5 to 1. I did this so I don't have to keep deleting it, but I still have to change it every time I switch files and want to run that file. It's pretty annoying, is there anyway to just run the files like normal without having to change the configurations?

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hodh.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IhMD.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44OUT.png)

Comment: Running a file NEED a configuration, which means HOW to run that file

Comment: so what can I do to immediately run each file without changing it everytime? @azro

Comment: Right-click the mouse anywhere inside the file view and press `Run ...` or `ctrl+shift+F10` on windows or just press the green arrow at the top-right corner

Comment: Use a main like https://pastebin.com/ScAN6nNP then pycharm will add a green arro next to it, so you can run it easily

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much @Tomerikoo , that is exactly what i was looking for. Is there any way to make it stop creating configurations? Or should I just leave it and let it keep creating and storing them at the top?

Comment: okay! thank you so much @azro , i'll definitely look into pastebin and find out what it does.

Comment: As azro said, configurations are necessary. It's just not so necessary to worry about them and deal with them, with any of the ways proposed above.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answer has been given in comment.

Comment: ah I see okay! i'm only saying this because i changed the location of one of my files yesterday and i couldn't run any of my other files because I didn't know that the old file configuration was still on.

Comment: okay! thanks guys!

Comment: @azro I don't quite agree with this close vote. If the question was solved through comments, they should be turned to an answer and accepted to "close" the question. It shouldn't be ***closed*** closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Collecting comments to an answer:</sup>

---

Running a file ***need*** a configuration, which means ***how*** to run that file.

It's just not so necessary to worry about them and deal with them, using one of these ways:

- Right-click the mouse anywhere inside the file view and press `Run <filename>`
- <kbd>ctrl+shift+F10</kbd> on windows
- Use a [*main* guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544752/should-i-use-a-main-method-in-a-simple-python-script) and Pycharm will add a small green arrow through which you can run the file directly:

  [image: An image showing a single line of code: if __name__ == "__main__": with a green arrow added next to it automatically. The arrow is highlighted with a red circle]

Comment: How do you make it a "community wiki" answer ?

Comment: There is a small check-box under the bottom-right corner of the answer's text field